# Find unique values from multiple different col in a every row

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

Apologies, I have no code because I am not quite sure where to start...

I need to find all the unique countries code from 6 different columns shown below and append them at the end in the Indicas.

For example:

| Residence 1 | Residence 2 | Residence 3 | Mail 1 | Mail 2 | Mail 3 | Indica 1 | Indica 2 | Indica 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CN | US | NULL | US | CN | NULL |  |  |  |
| US | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |  |  |
| US | CN | EU | NULL | NULL | NULL |  |  |  |

To fill the Indica to be like this:

| Residence 1 | Residence 2 | Residence 3 | Mail 1 | Mail 2 | Mail 3 | Indica 1 | Indica 2 | Indica 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CN | US | NULL | US | NULL | NULL | CN | US |  |
| US | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | US |  |  |
| US | CN | NULL | NULL | NULL | EU | US | CN | EU |

It looks deceptively easy yet I'm struggling hard with it.

Comment: "I have no code because I am not quite sure where to start." did you try any code? if so please include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have placed the table in B1:J4. you can use the following formula in all indica cells

```
=IF(UNIQUE($B3:$G3,TRUE)="NULL","",UNIQUE($B3:$G3,TRUE))
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please remember to upvote and mark the answer as useful if it works :)